# Is Windsor able to have collection of concrete class' instances registered?

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

If I have interface and implementing classes like

```
public interface IA {}
public class X : IA {}
public class Y : IA {}
```

then this registering is fine

```
var w = new WindsorContainer();
w.Register(Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<X>());
w.Register(Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<Y>());
```

same as

```
var w = new WindsorContainer();
w.Register(Component.For<IA>().Instance(new X()));
w.Register(Component.For<IA>().Instance(new Y()));
```

But if I try to register concrete classes as

```
var w = new WindsorContainer();
var x1 = new X();
var x2 = new X();
w.Register(Component.For<X>().Instance(x1));
w.Register(Component.For<X>().Instance(x2));
```

it throws an exception: `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException : Component X could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.`

If it is intended limitation - why? Is there any way to achieve collection resolve without adding interface that is not always necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make
>   sure you specify a unique name.

```
Component.For<X>().Instance(x1).Named("x1")
```

Comment: It's just a bit counter-intuitive for me. How it differs from component having explicit interface?

Comment: not at all. You'd observe the same behaviour if you created two components with same implementation class regardless of what you expose as a service.